# Setting ancestors in Symfony 2 ACL

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I noticed some references to the concept of 'ancestors' in the [Symfony 2 ACL documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html):

> ## Database Table Structure
>
> The default implementation uses five database tables as listed below. The tables are ordered from least rows to most rows in a typical application:
>
> ...
>
> - `acl_object_identity_ancestors`: This table allows all the ancestors of an ACL to be determined in a very efficient way.

I haven't been able to find any code that shows how to set/utilize ancestors though.  What is an example of how to set ancestor(s) for an `ObjectIdentity`?